# catkin_make install issue: File INSTALL cannot find

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running `$ catkin_make install`, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at HeartBeat/heart/cmake_install.cmake:40 (FILE):
  file INSTALL cannot find "/home/brandon/ros_ws/devel/include/heart_listener".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:83 (INCLUDE)
```

If I create the directory that it can't find, the install works. However, I would like a permanent fix for this issue. Why is this happening?

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(heart_listener)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs genmsg)
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)
catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS std_msgs roscpp)
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(heart_listener_node src/heart_listener.cpp)
add_dependencies(heart_listener_node std_msgs_gencpp)
target_link_libraries(heart_listener_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

My ROS workspace looks like this:

```
~/ros_ws/
-build    
-devel
-install
-src
--HeartBeat
---heart_listener
----msg
----src
----Package.xml
----CMakeLists.txt
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62567/catkin_make-install-issue:-file-install-cannot-find-.../) by [duffany1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4288/duffany1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2013-05-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that I wasn't using any custom messages for my project. I needed to remove `generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)` from `CMakeLists.txt`.

---

Originally posted by [duffany1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4288/duffany1/) with karma: 173 on 2013-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1